# Word VBA Code Improvement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a code to color user's input to a written questions. I am fairly new to vba, the code is working fine but I want to improve it, that is detect errors and incase something goes wrong with the code the documents still functions normally.

I have two types of input, either the user select something from dropdown menu or write his/her own answer (usually numbers, so I have a function to trim the answer for numbers incase there was character).

example:

Q:Number of work hours?
A: Five (5) ----> the code check the value (5) and based on it the "Five (5)" color changes to green.

I appreciate your help.

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As 
Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim store As String
Dim storeNum As Integer

 If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("high") = True Then
    store = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("high").Range.Text
    If store = "0" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("high").Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(103, 106, 110)
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("high").Range.Font.TextColor = vbRed
    End If
 End If

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("medium") = True Then

 End If

 If (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("bidders") = True) And (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Text <> "Number of primary bids received and alternatives") Then
        storeNum = ExtractNumber(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range)
        If storeNum > 7 Then
              ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        ElseIf (storeNum > 3) And (storeNum < 8) Then
              ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
         ElseIf storeNum < 4 Then
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Font.TextColor = vbRed
         End If
    End If

    For Each oContentControl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If oContentControl.Type = wdContentControlRichText Then
        oContentControl.Range.Font.Color = RGB(103, 106, 110)
        oContentControl.Range.Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
        oContentControl.Range.Font.Size = 11
        oContentControl.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
    End If
    Next
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

End Sub

Function ExtractNumber(rCell As Range)
Dim iCount As Integer, i As Integer
Dim sText As String
Dim lNum As String


sText = rCell

For iCount = Len(sText) To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sText, iCount, 1)) Then
        i = i + 1
        lNum = Mid(sText, iCount, 1) & lNum
    End If

    If i = 1 Then lNum = CInt(Mid(lNum, 1, 1))
Next iCount

ExtractNumber = CLng(lNum)
End Function
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you get any errors that you need to implement error handling or something? what kind of errors you expect. You should assume what could go wrong to get any help.

Comment: I do not expect errors, but I want to better understand the coding in VBA and how to better write in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... it is a broad question but there a few problems nonetheless:

```
If (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("bidders") = True) And ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Text <> "Number of primary bids 
received and alternatives") Then
```

Because both parts of the And are evaluated.  In other words, even if the bookmark "bidders" does not exist you are still asking for the text, which generates an error.

A better way would be to use a nested If:

```
If (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("bidders") = True) Then
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bidders").Range.Text <> "Number of primary bids received and alternatives") Then
        ' Your Code
    End If
End If
```

Also this If block is empty (best to delete it):

```
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("medium") = True Then

End If
```

You may also run into trouble with the content controls, sometimes they can be locked for editing in which case you may expect an error when you try to set the font `.name`, `.color`, `.size`.

You can test and set whether or not a content control is locked with this:

```
If activedocument.ContentControls(1).LockContents = True Then ' Prevent edit
If activedocument.ContentControls(1).LockContentControl = True Then ' Prevent delete
' Note you don't actually need the " = True", it is just there for clarity
```